# Is there a polar function symmetry about x-axis and the origin and non symmetry about y-axis?

Tags: polar-coordinates

Can I say if the polar function is symmetry about $x$-axis and about the origin, then the function must be symmetry about the $y$-axis?

Comment: I suppose "symmetry about $x$-axis" means the graph is a mirror image of itself reflected through the $x$-axis, but what is "symmetry about the origin"? Reflection? Rotation? Either? Both?

Comment: @DavidK Is there a second meaning for symmetry about the origin or is it one concept?

Comment: I would expect "symmetry about the origin" to mean there is some isometry that maps the origin to the origin and maps the graph of the function to the same graph. The isometry could be any isometry; if one such isometry exists, we have symmetry about the origin. I was wondering if you had a more restrictive definition.